# Python + Selenium - How to check an image which is styled with CSS and displayed as content?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, pseudo-element

[image: Details]
Normally a picture is gladly displayed via an ID. But in my example these images are displayed as content / character:

```
.fa-calendar-alt:before {
    Synchro : "\f073";
```

What can I do here?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? If it exists or it is going to be some complicated comparison to locate something?

Comment: He want's to know if he can check the "\f073" part through selenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to ckeck the "*content*" value of before *pseudo-element*.
In this case I'd suggest you to try to do it with JS. Look here to see how to run [JS code via selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345).

```
return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.far.fa-calendar-alt'), ':before')['content'];
```

After getting the value you can do simple string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

check for the class name if it exists then execute your next step.

e.g. `driver.find_element_by_class_name("far fa-calendar-alt")`

or you can just define it's xpath. Let me know if you need to know how to find the xpath.

Edit: Xpath example:

`//div//i[@class="far fa-calendar-alt"]`

Answer (score 4):

A bit of more details about your usecase would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer. However, the desired element is applied with a A CSS [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

Usually the [Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449375/how-to-send-a-date-directly-as-text-to-a-calendar-control-with-readonly-attribut/57453876#57453876) elements are interactive. So to identify the *Calendar* element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  calendar = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.far.fa-calendar-alt")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  calendar = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='far fa-calendar-alt']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### CSS Pseudo-elements

Now, if your usecase is to extract the value of the content property of the [`::before`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) element i.e. **`Synchro : "\f073"`** you can use the following solution:

```
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.fa-calendar-alt'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')"
print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python/59706267#59706267)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things here. Your code is font-awesome library. And the calendar icon is suppose to use the class `fa-calendar-alt`.

Now if you expect your icon to be a calendar, just checking if the class `fa-calendar-alt` exists on your element should be good enough to check if the calendar icon will appear.

Once this class is there you can assume that the calendar icon will be displayed. Now the other assumption that we make is that the font-awesome library was actually included by the html, because if for some reason the library is not included then even though class of calendar is correct, the icon will still not load. So for that you can check if a given class actually exists in CSS or not. Below thread can help you for the same

[How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)

I would never worry about checking this, because chances of such occurrences will always be very low.

I would discourage checking content values of the class itself, as you are then making it implementation dependent, which you shouldn't. Like in Font Awesome 5.0, it use SVG to do all this instead of a font