# How to select values from multiple layers of dropdown menu using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, datepicker, setattribute

I am struggling to struggling with selecting a date from a drop down menu on a site:

https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk&t=hk

It is seen there is a calendar date drop-down menu with HTML code

```
<input name="txtShareholdingDate" type="text" value="2022/07/15" id="txtShareholdingDate" class="input-searchDate active" data-reset="2022/07/16" readonly="readonly">
```

My first strategy to select an arbitrary date is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(link)
dateelem = browser.find_element_by_id('txtShareholdingDate')
dateelem.click()
```

And on headless browser it appears to have 3 drop-down columns: "Year", "Month", "Day".

From here I have been stuck trying to select a random date here (say 2021/09/21), and I googled quite a number of workarounds. A majority of those proposed solutions involved using `find_element_by_css_selector()` or xpaths with nested tags, but I always got back errors like "Unable to locate element".

Another kind of solutions I tried was

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

dateelem = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('txtShareholdingDate'))
```

and then the following error would appear:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>
```

So how could I work around the multiple layers of drop-down menu to get a general date?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, just change it as you want

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('txtShareholdingDate').value='2022/03/14'")
sleep(7)
btnSearch=driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnSearch")
btnSearch.click()
```

**Import**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: the solution works perfect! Thx ~~~

Answer (score 0):

The [datepicker](/questions/tagged/datepicker) is generated through an *`<input>`* tag

[image: date_dropdown]

So you can't use [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class.

Further, the *`<input>`* element is having the **`readonly="readonly"`** attribute set.

---

### Solution

To select a different date you can use [`removeAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453876/7429447) method to remove the **`readonly`** attribute and then use [`setAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453876/7429447) method to set the new value as follows:

```
driver.get('https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk&t=hk')
calendar = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtShareholdingDate")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", calendar)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','2021/08/16')", calendar)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: hkexnews]